# Why "if(!!variable)" instead of "if(variable)"?

Tags: javascript

In someone else's code I found this way to test the existence of a variable :

```
if(!!variable) {
  //Do something
} else {
  //Something else
}
```

Is there a reason to test with `if(!!variable)` instead of `if(variable)` ? Is it a good practice?

Comment: Why, indeed?  Seems less readable to me.  Can't wait to see what others say.

Comment: Only use of `!!` i can think of is to convert something to `bool`. E.g. `var i = !!0; console.log(i); //false (instead of 0)`.

Comment: In this particular case it doesn't make any difference, I think. But it's useful when you want to convert an arbitrary value into a boolean (when you later save it to the database, or something)

Comment: `if` converts always to boolean.

Comment: Some use it as explicit coercion instead of Boolean. Some find it more readable to explicitly tell they want to evaluate a boolean value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a reason to test with `if(!!variable)` instead of `if(variable)`?

No.

Using `if()` will coerce the condition to a boolean anyway, there's no need to manually do it.  Using this sort of syntax makes sense when you want to guarantee you've got a boolean elsewhere, for example if you wanted to log the truthiness of the expression:

```
console.log(!!variable)
```

This will ensure that you get either `true` or `false` logged, rather than the original value of the variable.  But inside an `if`?  It makes no difference.

Comment: It's also useful along with other logical ops: `0 && true` yields 0 for instance. If you expect a boolean value, try: `!!0 && true`

Comment: @LUH3417 Indeed.  But both of those will behave the same way inside an `if()`, which is what the question was asking.

Answer (score 0):

No, in the case of a if, their is usually no reason to write that in JS.

I would not call it bad practice, since it can often come from programmer coming from strongly typed language, and is a common quick way to do the conversion to bool in thoses language.

It can also be used to emphasise the importance of the truthiness of the value in a long if, and show the programmer didn t forget to put the condition.

TL:DR: As for a lot of things: it may not be good practice, but it only become bad practice if your team is not used to that practice, either train them, document, or leave it.

Answer (score -2):

Double negation is a bit of a hacky way (IMHO) to convert a variable to bool. using `!` on variable coerces it to a bool and negates it, and using it again convert it back to the 'correct' value. So `!!0 === false`

As mentioned by James there is no reason to do this inside an if statement. The only reason really to do this would be to coerce to a bool for logging purposes or similar so the value logged is `true` or `false` rather than `0`, an empty string etc

Comment: What is the difference between `if(0)` and `if(!!0)`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev There is no difference really because `if` coerces the value anyway.

Comment: This was my attempt at hinting that your answer doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Fair enough. I misunderstood the question, but have tried to expand a bit (for what its worth)

Comment: I see that and I retracted my downvote. :)

Answer (score -3):

Double `!` (`!!`) is not an operator. It's just ! twice - **double negation**.

Comment: But why use it specifically here?  It's not like it's being assigned to a variable that you want to guarantee is a bool.

Comment: How does this answer the question? JFYI, the question isn't "what is this `!!` operator and what does it do?".